# Listagem no Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Galera, estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que gerencia inscrições de cursos, na minha tela de listagem dos Cursos está dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Só que eu preciso fazer uma nova tela com outro tipo de listagem, e gostaria que a listagem fosse por curso e mostrasse os alunos inscritos neste curso. Por exemplo, a tela teria que ser assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém pode me ajudar?

**Model Aluno**

```
public class Aluno
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo Nome é obrigatório")]
    [MinLength(4, ErrorMessage = "O campo Nome deve ter no mínimo 4 caracteres")]
    [Display(Name = "Nome")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "CPF")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo CPF é obrigatório")]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    [CPFAtributo]
    public string CPF { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "RG")]
    public string RG { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "E-mail")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo E-mail é obrigatório")]
    [RegularExpression(@"\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*", ErrorMessage = "Endereço de e-mail informado não é válido.")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Usuário")]
    [MinLength(4, ErrorMessage = "O campo Usuário deve ter no mínimo 4 caracteres")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo Usuário é obrigatório")]
    public string Usuario { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Senha")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo Senha é obrigatório")]
    public string Senha { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "Confirmar Senha")]
    [Compare("Senha", ErrorMessage = "As senhas não conferem")]
    public string ConfirmaSenha { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Telefone Celular")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe um número de Celular")]
    public string Telefone_Celular { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Telefone Fixo")]
    public string Telefone_Fixo { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Endereço")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O Endereço é obrigatório")]
    public string Endereco { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Estado")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe um Estado")]
    public string Estado { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Complemento")]
    public string Complemento { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Matrícula")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe a Matrícula")]
    public string Matricula { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Cargo Efetivo")]
    public string Cargo_Efetivo { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Cargo Comissionado")]
    public string Cargo_Comissionado { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Telefone Orgao")]
    public string Telefone_Orgao { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Nome Chefe Imediato")]
    public string Nome_Chefia_Imediato { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Telefone Chefe Imediato")]
    public string Telefone_Chefia_Imediato { get; set; }

    public string Perfil { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Curso> Cursos { get; set; }
```

**Model Curso**

```
public class Curso
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Curso")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo Curso é obrigatório")]
    public string Nome_Curso { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Sigla")]
    public string Sigla { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Ementa")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A Ementa é obrigatório")]
    public string Ementa { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Aprovado")]
    public bool Aprovado { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Data de Início")]
    public DateTime Dt_Inicio { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Data Final")]
    public DateTime Dt_Fim { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Turno")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe um Turno")]
    public string Turno { get; set; }


    public string Status { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Quantidade de Vagas")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A quantidade de Vagas é obrigatório")]
    public int Qtd_Vagas { get; set; }

    public int AlunoId { get; set; }

    public Aluno Aluno { get; set; }
```

**Código de consulta conforme primeira imagem acima**

```
public ActionResult MeusCursos()
    {
        var cursos = db.Cursos.Include(a => a.Aluno).ToList();
        return View(cursos);
    }
```

Comment: Se possível, poste a estrutura de suas tabelas, juntamente com o código que você está utilizando para realizar a consulta.

Comment: Editei a pergunta @Randrade essas são minhas tabelas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A modelagem está incorreta. Do jeito que está, um `Curso` pertence a um só `Aluno`.

O correto é criar uma tabela associativa. Sugiro algo assim:

```
public class AlunoCurso 
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AlunoId { get; set; }
    public int CursoId { get; set; }
    public bool Aprovado { get; set; }

    public virtual Aluno Aluno { get; set }
    public virtual Curso Curso { get; set; }
}
```

Mude `Aluno` para:

```
public class Aluno 
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...

    public virtual ICollection<AlunoCurso> AlunoCursos { get; set; }
}
```

E `Curso` para:

```
public class Curso
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...

    public virtual ICollection<AlunoCurso> AlunoCursos { get; set; }
}
```

`virtual` é importante para o Entity Framework reconhecer que é uma propriedade de navegação (ou seja, que a propriedade não é persistida em banco, e apenas atua como um facilitador da carga preguiçosa).

O *Controller* ficaria assim:

```
public ActionResult MeusCursos()
{
    var cursos = db.AlunoCursos
                     .Include(a => a.Aluno)
                     .Include(a => a.Curso)
                     .ToList();

    return View(cursos);
}
```

Comment: Eu preciso desses dois tipos de listagem uma eu já tenho a outra não, nesse novo cenário ai eu terei os **dois** tipos de **listas** citados acima @Cigano? E quanto ao uso do `virtual` não apareceria no banco o campo de relacionamento entre as tabelas, é isso? Por exemplo, não apareceria a propriedade **AlunoId** dentro da tabela **Curso**

Comment: Ei @Cigano eu fiz a alteração baseado no seu exemplo só que a tabela associativa **AlunoCurso**, não está associando meu Id de Curso nem de Aluno nela, tá ficando vazia. Mesmo eu cadastrando novos cursos e alunos. Os campos **Id**, **AlunoID**, **CursoId** e **Aprovado** estão vazios, não era pra associar a medida que eu fosse cadastrando eles?

Comment: @Novato Sim, terá os dois tipos de listas apenas com a associação. Não, o relacionamento das tabelas é feito normalmente. A propriedade de navegação só vale **para o código da aplicação**, e não para o banco. A ideia é que ele torne o desenvolvimento mais fácil e habilite facilmente pra você o recurso de carga preguiçosa.

Comment: @Novato Não existe mágica. Além de cadastrar alunos e cursos, é preciso um passo adicional que faça a associação entre alunos e cursos, coisa que creio que ainda não existe no seu código.

Comment: E como eu faria esse passo adicional para fazer essa associação entre eles @Cigano?

Comment: [Respondi aqui, na sua outra pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/67538/como-fazer-associa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-um-id-no-asp-net-mvc/67551#67551).