# Como fazer associação de um Id no asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Galera, estou com um pequeno problema na minha aplicação, que é um gerenciador de Cursos. O problema é que "aluno" tem que se inscrever em algum curso, só que eu não estou conseguindo fazer a associação do aluno ao curso. Na minha tela de inscrição tenho um botão "inscrição", onde, o aluno clica e esse botão deveria associar o "aluno" à aquele determinado curso, além de associar, esse botão também faz o decremento de vagas daquele curso de acordo com o que os alunos vão se inscrevendo.

**Estou tentando fazer assim**
`Meu Controller`

```
public ActionResult Inscricao(int? id)
    {
        using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
        {

            // Aqui pegaria o aluno logado.
            // E aqui é onde tenho que fazer a associação do aluno ao curso.

            Curso curso = new Curso();

            //Tentei fazer assim, mas não consegui
            curso = db.Cursos.Include(a => a.Aluno).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);

            curso.Qtd_Vagas--;
            db.Entry(curso).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();

            scope.Complete();
        }

        return View("Inscricao", db.Cursos.ToList());

    }
```

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/67387/listagem-no-asp-net-mvc/67474

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Como expliquei pra você aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/67387/listagem-no-asp-net-mvc/67474), como a modelagem mudou, o que precisa ser feito é criar um objeto de associação entre `Aluno` e `Curso` e depois decrementar a quantidade de vagas de um `Curso`.

Ou seja:

```
public ActionResult Inscricao(int? id)
{
    using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
    {

        // Aqui pegaria o aluno logado.
        var aluno = db.Alunos.FirstOrDefault(/* Aqui vai uma condição */);
        if (aluno == null) return View("Inscricao", db.Cursos.ToList());

        var curso = db.Cursos.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
        if (curso == null) return View("Inscricao", db.Cursos.ToList());

        var alunoCurso = new AlunoCurso {
            Aluno = aluno, 
            Curso = curso}
        };

        db.AlunoCursos.Add(alunoCurso);
        db.SaveChanges();

        curso.Qtd_Vagas--;
        db.Entry(curso).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();

        scope.Complete();
    }

    return View("Inscricao", db.Cursos.ToList());
}
```

Comment: Funcionou @Cigano, só que agora estou com outro problema. Quando eu vou na tela de Inscrição, o botão "inscrição" só decrementa e associa o cara se eu passar o Id na URL. Exemplo: Curso/Inscrição **Assim não funciona**, agora se eu fizer assim **Curso/Inscrição/1** funciona. Como eu faço pra ele decrementar e associar sem ter que ficar passando o Id na URL? Faço outra pergunta?

Comment: @Novato Sim, faça outra pergunta. Envolve usar `POST` e mais alguns ajustes na *Action*.

Comment: Olha link ai @Cigano http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/67560/bot%C3%A3o-s%C3%B3-funcionar-se-passar-o-id-na-url-no-asp-net-mvc